# Planning custom screen layout for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi, android-screen-support

I have a custom layout with `width="match_parent"`. Layout consists of big circle in the center and smaller one just next to it.

On my screen I have found the dimensions that I like and now I want to make it look similar across all devices.

My device is Galaxy S8 with display metrics reported as:

```
DisplayMetrics {
    density=3.5,
    width=1440,
    height=2960,
    scaledDensity=2.8,
    xdpi=562.707,
    ydpi=565.293
}
```

So as I understand I have 411dp in width available.

For dimensions I have

- Big Circle in the center 110dp radius.
- Smaller circle next to it 21dp radius.
- The distance between them 20dp.

Now I wonder how should I go with this. I have 2 options in my mind. First will be to create separate values for other screen densities, or just convert this dimensions into percentage and do the layout programmatically.

My problem with first option is that some devices (like mine) have screen zoom which changes `scaledDensity` making it look totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can support different screen sizes use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout):

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

You can use those attributes to specify your views size in precents:

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
```

For example, single button that is equal to 50% of the screen both in height and width:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look something like this:**

[image]

**One more thing**, because different phones got different screen size you better not use fixed size dimensions (`50dp` for example )on your views.

I can recommend using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes (In addition to what I mentioned above - `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent`).

Comment: This is interesting approach as I never tried ConstraintLayout before. can layout_constraintHeight_percent be same as width?

Comment: Yes, and if you would like to display a square you can just use  `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`. start by reading the documentation. it is really user friendly

Comment: This sounds like less pain than what I was gonna do so I'm gonna at least try it. Accepting answer :)

Comment: Feel free to write me in my [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tamir-abutbul-10a695178/) if you are having any problems